# How do I make the program keep track of the score of a "stone-paper-scissors" game?

Tags: javascript

I am coding using Javascript.

http://www.programmingbasics.org/en/beginner/random.html
(Please press 'next' until you arrive on the 'stone-paper-scissors' section.

This is the code I've created so far:

```
while(true){you = choose("Make your choice", "rock", "paper", "scissors");

com = random(3);
if (com == 1){show("rock");}
if (com == 2){show("paper");}
if (com == 3){show("scissors");}

w = "you win";
l = "you lose";
d = "draw";

cs = 0;
ys = 0;

if (com == 1){
if (you == 1){show(d);
cs = cs + 0;
ys = ys + 0;}
if (you == 2){show(w);
ys = ys + 1;}
if (you == 3){show(l);
cs = cs + 1;}
}

if (com == 2){
if (you == 1){show(l);
cs = cs + 1;}
if (you == 2){show(d);
cs = cs + 0;
ys = ys + 0;}
if (you == 3){show(w);
ys = ys + 1;}
}

if (com == 3){
if (you == 1){show(w);
ys = ys + 1;}
if (you == 2){show(l);
cs = cs + 1;}
if (you == 3){show(d);
cs = cs + 0;
ys = ys + 0;}
}

show("Computer score: "+cs);
show("Your score: "+ys);

if (cs == 3){break;}
if (ys == 3){break;}
}
```

Whereby 'cs' = computer score and 'ys' = your score.

How do I keep track of the score while starting a new game?

Thank you.

Comment: simply initialize the 'cs' and the 'ys' before the while loop, because right now you are resetting it every game

Comment: Why aren't you using `var`?

Answer (score 1):

Define the variables outside the function, or they will be set back to zero each loop:

```
var cs = 0;
var ys = 0;

while(true){you = choose("Make your choice", "rock", "paper", "scissors");

com = random(3);
if (com == 1){show("rock");}
if (com == 2){show("paper");}
if (com == 3){show("scissors");}

w = "you win";
l = "you lose";
d = "draw";

if (com == 1){
if (you == 1){show(d);
cs = cs + 0;
ys = ys + 0;}
if (you == 2){show(w);
ys = ys + 1;}
if (you == 3){show(l);
cs = cs + 1;}
}

if (com == 2){
if (you == 1){show(l);
cs = cs + 1;}
if (you == 2){show(d);
cs = cs + 0;
ys = ys + 0;}
if (you == 3){show(w);
ys = ys + 1;}
}

if (com == 3){
if (you == 1){show(w);
ys = ys + 1;}
if (you == 2){show(l);
cs = cs + 1;}
if (you == 3){show(d);
cs = cs + 0;
ys = ys + 0;}
}

show("Computer score: "+cs);
show("Your score: "+ys);

if (cs == 3){break;}
if (ys == 3){break;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you defined `cs = 0; ys = 0;` inside `While()` they are reset on each cycle. Move those outside of the while loop.

To increase `int` by 1 you can use `i++` (or i-- to decrease) instead of `i = i + 1;`

`cs = cs + 0;` does nothing